# TimeoutError - Traceback (most recent call last), Django-app - sending e-mails. Python

Tags: python, django, gmail, mailgun

I am trying to use 'mailgun' and gmail mail to send emails from my Django application, but each time I receive an error.

In my application I have the following code:

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mailgun.org'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'aaa@mg.xxx.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '#########'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

then I run the command from the command line:

**manage.py shell**

```
[1] from django.core.mail import send_mail
[2] send_mail('subject', 'body of the message', 'aaa@mg.xxx.com', ['
recipient@aaa.com'])
```

Do I use gmail, or with 'mailguna' always get the same error

**Error:**

```
TimeoutError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-4c559962ca7f> in <module>()
----> 1 send_mail('subject', 'body of the message', '###@mg.###.com', ['###@###.com'])

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\__init__.py in send_mail(subject, message, from_email, recipient_list, fail_silently, auth_user, auth_password, connection, html_message)
     58         mail.attach_alternative(html_message, 'text/html')
     59
---> 60     return mail.send()
     61
     62

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\message.py in send(self, fail_silently)
    289             # send to.
    290             return 0
--> 291         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])
    292
    293     def attach(self, filename=None, content=None, mimetype=None):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py in send_messages(self, email_messages)
    101             return
    102         with self._lock:
--> 103             new_conn_created = self.open()
    104             if not self.connection or new_conn_created is None:
    105                 # We failed silently on open().

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\mail\backends\smtp.py in open(self)
     61             })
     62         try:
---> 63             self.connection = self.connection_class(self.host, self.port, **connection_params)
     64
     65             # TLS/SSL are mutually exclusive, so only attempt TLS over

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py in __init__(self, host, port, local_hostname, timeout, source_address)
    249
    250         if host:
--> 251             (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
    252             if code != 220:
    253                 self.close()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py in connect(self, host, port, source_address)
    334         if self.debuglevel > 0:
    335             self._print_debug('connect:', (host, port))
--> 336         self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
    337         self.file = None
    338         (code, msg) = self.getreply()

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\smtplib.py in _get_socket(self, host, port, timeout)
    305             self._print_debug('connect: to', (host, port), self.source_address)
    306         return socket.create_connection((host, port), timeout,
--> 307                                         self.source_address)
    308
    309     def connect(self, host='localhost', port=0, source_address=None):

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    725
    726     if err is not None:
--> 727         raise err
    728     else:
    729         raise error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    714             if source_address:
    715                 sock.bind(source_address)
--> 716             sock.connect(sa)
    717             # Break explicitly a reference cycle
    718             err = None

TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]
```

I tried to change the settings 'TLS', 'mail port' and 'SSL' but they always ended with the same error.

When the code runs outside the application everything works fine:

**file_works_properly.py**

```
import smtplib

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

msg = MIMEText('Title')  #Tresc wiadomosci
msg['Subject'] = "Hello world"
msg['From']    = "XXX@mg.bbb.com"
msg['To']      = "ccc@ccc.com"

s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.mailgun.org', 587)

s.login('###@mg.bbb.com', '3###baa5e1f3###-26fa###0987')
s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
s.quit()
```

Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: It looks as if your server can't connect to port 587 on `smtp.mailgun.org`. Perhaps it's a firewall or proxy server issue. If you can't get the connection to work, you might want to look at a package like [django-anymail](https://github.com/anymail/django-anymail) which allows you to send emails using mailgun's API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The addition of three imports solved my problem (for 'python manage.py shell' or to the views.py file):

**imports (in views.py/shell):**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.conf import settings
```

The rest of the activities are unchanged:

**settings.py**

```
[...]
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassowrd'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

**To send e-mail (in views.py/shell)**

```
send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [to_list_email])
```

(*Important for gmail.com) - and often this [option](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) must be enabled.